# Kendo grid Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a table with 4 columns. [ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,ADDRESS]. I am displaying the 3 cloumns[ID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME] on the kendogrid. What i am trying to do is on clicking the FIRSTNAME it should display the ADDRESS on a new window.But i am not getting it. I tried to get the link on the FIRSTNAME but dont know how to proceed later. i am new to this concept.Below is my code.Do i need to create a kendo grid for the Address or how it works.What i want is a hyperlink on ID to show ADDRESS.

Thanks.

```
 Grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                      dataSource:gridDS,
                      height: 450,
                      pageable: false,
                      sortable: true,
                          binding: true
         columns: [

                 {
                     field: "ID",
                     title: "ID",
                     headerTemplate: '<span class="tbl-hdr">ID</span>',
                     attributes: {
                         style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px"
                     },
                     width: 85
                 },
                 {
                     field: "FIRSTNAME",
                     title: "FIRSTNAME",
                     headerTemplate: '<span class="tbl-hdr">FIRSTNAME</span>', 
                     template: '<a href="#=FIRSTNAME#">#=ADDRESS#</a>',
                     attributes: {
                         style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px"
                     },
                     width: 25
                 },
                 {
                     field: "LASTNAME",
                     title: "LASTNAME",
                     headerTemplate: '<span class="tbl-hdr">LASTNAME</span>',
                     attributes: {
                         style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight:bold; font-size: 12px"
                     },
                     width: 85
                 },

                  {
                      command: [
                        {
                            name: "destroy",
                            template: "<div class='k-button delete-btn'><span class='k-icon k-delete'></span></div>",
                            text: "remove"
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Edit",
                            template: "<div class='k-button edit-btn'><span class='k-icon k-edit'></span></div>",

                        },

                      ],
                      width: 40,
                      attributes: {
                          style: "vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"
                      }
                  },
             ],
             editable: "popup"
         }).data('kendoGrid');
     }
```

Comment: ***Please do not update the original question with code from answer.*** Your question will be out of sync with the answers.

Comment: `clicking the FIRSTNAME it should display the ADDRESS on a new window` - Could you explain what it means?

Comment: The adress is a clob datatype it has few lines of info. So when we click on Firstname it gives a Popup or message box that displays the Address info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not a *kendo* issue, is pretty much about JS/jQuery. What I suggest is to bind an event on the grid to get all click events from that link in your template. Then, you can get the *clicked* `dataItem` with the row data of it.

```
.on("click", "a.name-link", function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var dataItem = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(tr);

    window.alert(dataItem.Address);
});
```

[Working Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oceZO)

What is unclear is how you want to *open a new window* with the Address. What you mean:A fresh new browser tab/window or anything like a JS Popup inside your app?

If you want a new browser tab/window, you should pass the row `id` to it using [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) and then in this window, you will have to hit the database again to show the information. Now, if want a javascript popup(e.g. [Bootstrap's Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)) inside your app, you can use the previous retrieved `dataItem` to fill it. The information is already there.

Comment: Even a popup window is fine

Comment: I updated the code to this but i am getting error as Error: Unable to get property 'on' of undefined or null reference

Comment: I am getting this error as soon as the page is loading but the pop up window with the address details is working.

Comment: @vana Strange because if the error was related to the event ive sugested, the alert should not work

Comment: Is there a way can we write this function at the field template instead of page load.

Comment: I got this issue only after i added the event suggested by you but the alert is working after i click on ID.

Comment: I updated my code with the total page load of grid can you check it now please

Comment: I got it i didnt dind the grid to it . Its working now. Your code worked for me. thanks a lot

Comment: @vana I'm glad it worked!! You should check this - or the answer that works for you - as the accepted answer. [See this in case you need help on that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/223068).

Comment: I tried to click on answer but it says i need more reputation

Comment: @vana note that you have to click on the *check* mark, not on the arrows, those indeed required reputation, but the accept action don't.

Comment: i have one more doubt posted a question can you check it if possible

Comment: @vana ok, post here the link of the new question.

Comment: @ DontVoteMeDown http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851695/kendo-ui-dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code. You can click on firstName to view address.

If you want to go a little bit further, you can click on Address button to view address in pop-up window.

[Sample at Telerik Kendo UI Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ASinu)

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        a {
            cursor: pointer;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        .k-grid-update {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
        <a onclick="display('#=address#')">#=firstName#</a>
    </script>
    <script id="popup-editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        #=address#
    </script>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [
              { field: "id" },
              { field: "firstName", template: kendo.template($("#row-template").html()) },
              { field: "lastName" },
              { command: [{ name: "edit", text: { edit: "Address", cancel: "Close", update: "Close" } }]
              }
            ],
            dataSource: {
                data: [
                  { id: 1, firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe", address: "123 Street" },
                  { id: 2, firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", address: "456 Street" }
                ],
                schema: {
                    model: { id: "id" }
                }
            },
            editable: {
                mode: "popup",
                window: { title: 'Address' },
                template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
            }
        });

        function display(address) {
            alert(address);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ADDRESS is a field not a page

Comment: Sorry its an requirement