# Kendo UI Dropdownlist

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJz5f.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBH1o.png)I have a kendo grid displaying ID,NID,SID(Student table) and some other fields.Now when i want to add new Student the NID field must me a dropdownlist populating the values from the database. How can we do this. What should be in the data-source . I wrote a query to get the NID. but how would i use it. Or is this  wrong
Thanks

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <label for="ID">ID</label>
                </div>
                <div data-container-for="data.ID">
                    <input id="id" data-bind="value: data.ID" style="width: 250px;" name="ID" type="text" />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <label for="NID" id="lcid">NID</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input id="cid" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Service:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cid").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "NID",
        dataValueField: "NID",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    url: "/Services/getNID",
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you noticed your `data-bind` attribute value is not correct?

Comment: you mean " are missing

Comment: Sure. Now, if I got you right, you just want to populate the ddl with remote data. If i'm right, there are some demos for that, [check this](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource).

Comment: Yes but what should we give in the label declaration is my question

Comment: Sry, I don't get you.

Comment: Syntax to declare the datasource of how we are getting the data to that combo box. CAn you show me if you have any example

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource

Comment: I tried but not working the dropdownlist is empty

Comment: Can you fix the html you've posted?  As it is now, it doesn't make sense and it's hard to tell what you are trying to do.

The outer div, and table are missing closing tags.  There is an additional td open tag, but no closing tag.  The second tr doesn't have a closing tag.

Comment: Yes updated and added the service i am using and attached the picture

Comment: Nice, now, what is the problem with the widget? Did it doesn't reaches the remote url? It seems that you don't need `jsonp` as your url call a path of the same domain. Try using `json` as `dataType` instead.

Comment: No still its not triggering the URl

Comment: Can you call the service using dev tools in your browser (like Postman in chrome)?  What do you see when you navigate to the service url in your browser?  Does it return the data you are expecting?

Comment: @Whipdancer Yes i see the data from the response body but somehow its not seen on the dropdown list

Comment: Can you include a sample of the data returned, including the full structure?

Comment: ["Apache_Sessionlinker_Log_size_check","Ariba_inbound_file_gap","DW_Rural_table_check","EDI_key_process_check"]</string>

Comment: Is that the full structure as well?  It literally just returns an array of string values? Or is the trailing `</string>` part of a larger XML response?

Comment: You should look at the demo link that @DontVoteMeDown posted earlier, but specifically, look at the sample service they use.  You can see the data that is returned by opening it in your browser.  [Here is the link to the products data in the demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products)

Comment: Its is a trailing and i dont see any error in service

Comment: Can you post the full response from your service?  The snippet you posted in not a valid JSON result.

Comment: Added a new snippet with name Response